# JGoodies Maven plugin NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven-plugin, jgoodies

I am doing a JGoodies GUI application using maven. The program successfully run on any idea, but when I created executible jar file with dependencies, jar file is also created successfully except running it there is an error :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at bemukan.downloadAccelerator.Home.(Home.java:23
        at bemukan.downloadAccelerator.Main.main(Main.java:15)

Thats there is an NullPointerException. I wonder whether jgoodies maven plugin for creating jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding following plugin to the pom.xml, It provided to convert *.form files to *.java files

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>ideauidesigner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
           <execution>
              <goals>
                 <goal>javac2</goal>
              </goals>
           </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <debug>true</debug>
          <failOnError>true</failOnError>

        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```